# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel white space

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a custom accessory arrow in my UITableViewCell:

```
    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "arrow_settings"))
```

After this I set detailTextLabel this way:

```
   cell.detailTextLabel?.text = settings.detailText + "  "
```

I add white space to give some space between detailTextLabel and the accessory but the white spaces are ignored at runtime! What do I do to give a gap between accessory view and detail text label?

Comment: Is detailTextLabel.text truncate at the end?

Comment: It ignores spaces when presenting. Don't know why.

Comment: Can you explain the problem with some more details, a screenshot and some more code would help.

Comment: I think the code and details are sufficient. I am trying to increase space between the accressory(>) and detailTextLabel. The workaround I tried above is putting white spaces in detailTextLabel.text. But it doesn't work.